# Proving $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$ is free given that $M$ is a free $A$-module both of rank $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, ring-homomorphism

I am attempting to prove that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$ is free given that $M$ is a free $A$ module.

So, currently I am using the fact that $\phi \in \operatorname{Hom}_A(M,A)$ is dependent on how it acts on our basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ for our $A$ module $M$. Thus by defining our basis of homomorphism as $\{\phi_1,...,\phi_n\}$ and $\phi_i(e_j)=\delta_{i,j}$.

However, we will need to give some specificity to $\delta_{i,j}$, to be honest I am very confused.
Maybe the fact my $A$ module $M$ is module isomorphic to $A^n$ may help...

I would appreciate a push in the right direction. Sorry about the vagueness of my attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $A$ is a commutative ring with unity $1_A$. Then it works exactly as in the vector space: $\delta_{i,j}=1_A$ if $i=j$, otherwise $\delta_{i,j}=0_A$, where $0_A$ is the identity element of the additive abelian group underlying the ring $A$.

Actually, in this way we can show that there is an isomorphism of free modules (of finite rank) over $A$: $$M\cong \text{Hom}_A(M,A),$$ defined exactly as you suggested on a basis, and then extended to all elements.

Comment: I can be more explicit if you need more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot, much simpler than I thought :)

Comment: You’re welcome! If it solves your question, please accept the answer so other users know that it is solved!